# Como gerar sumário de comentários de métodos, propriedades e etc no C#

Tags: c#

É o seguinte pessoal. Sei que para criar um sumário em um determinado Método é só colocar "///" no Visual Studio que o IntelliSense, põe automaticamente o seguinte:

Exemplo:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ligacao"> "Server = localhost; Integrated security = SSPI; database = Nome do Banco de dados"; </param>
    /// <param name="nomeTabela"> Nome da tabela em questão </param>
    /// <param name="nomeCampo"> Nome do campo pertencente a tabela em questão </param>
    /// <returns> Retorna o id atualmente disponível </returns>
    public static int IdDisponivel(SqlConnection ligacao, string nomeTabela, string nomeCampo)
    {
        int id = -1;

        string query = string.Format("SELECT MAX({0}) AS IdMax FROM {1}", nomeCampo, nomeTabela);
        DataTable dados = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(query, ligacao);

        try
        {
            adaptador.Fill(dados);

            //Verifica se a tabela está vazia ou não
            if (DBNull.Value.Equals(dados.Rows[0][0]))
                id = 1;
            else
                id = Convert.ToInt16(dados.Rows[0][0]) + 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MsgBox.Show("Erro:\n" + ex.Message, "Banco de Dados", TipoIcone.Erro);
        }
        finally
        {
            dados.Dispose();
            adaptador.Dispose();
        }

        return id;
    }
```

Se eu utilizar algum Método interno do próprio C# e deixar o mouse em cima desse Método ele informa os Parâmetros, tipo de retorno, em fim, tudo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que, caso eu escreva algum código (com o meu sumário todo preenchido) em uma DLL (como pode ser visto logo acima um dos meus métodos) e utilize essa DLL em um outro projeto meu, eu não vejo as minhas anotações que deixei no sumário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem observar na imagem logo acima, o meu sumário não apareceu.

Fiquei sabendo que era necessário criar e configurar um local para o arquivo de sumário XML, para que todas as minhas aplicações que usassem minhas DLL's pudessem "ver" os meus sumários, do mesmo jeito que consigo quando uso os métodos internos do C#. Mas, não sei como fazer isso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Desde já agradeço a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que os comments sejam exportados junto com a DLL um arquivo .xml com esses metadados deve ser gerado, e também deve estar junto com a DLL.

Para fazer isso, no *Visual Studio* vá nas propriedades do projeto (pode ser ao clicar o botão direito sobre o projeto), em `Build`, na opição *"XML Documentantion file"*.

Note que o arquivo deve ter o mesmo nome da DLL, por exemplo:

Projeto.Bananas.XXX.dll
Projeto.Bananas.XXX.xml

Comment: Ok. Muito obrigado pela resposta. Vou testar.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

Comment: não esqueça de aceitar a resposta então :)